# How to get text file size in MarkLogic

Tags: xquery, marklogic, marklogic-10

I need to get text file size in MarkLogic. I am reading log file where I want to know how much the log has grown on a particular date.

Below is the code I have written:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";

declare function local:convertToKilobytes($sizeInCharacters as xs:integer) as xs:decimal 
{
 $sizeInCharacters * 2 div 1024
};

let $error-log := "C:\Program Files\MarkLogic\Data\Logs\ErrorLog.txt"
let $logLines := fn:tokenize(xdmp:filesystem-file($error-log), '\r?\n')
let $uniqueDates := distinct-values(
                    for $line in $logLines
                    let $logDate := fn:substring($line, 1, 10) 
                    where $logDate ne ''
                   return $logDate
                                  )
let $currentSize := sum(for $line in $logLines return string-length($line))

let $logEntries := 
                for $date in $uniqueDates
                let $sizeInCharacters := sum(for $l in $logLines where fn:contains($l, $date) return string-length($l))
                let $sizeInKilobytes := local:convertToKilobytes($sizeInCharacters)
                return
                <log-entry date="{$date}" size-in-kilobytes="{$sizeInKilobytes}"/>

return
<log-growth>{ $logEntries }</log-growth>
```

from the above code I am getting the result is:

```
<log-growth>
  <log-entry date="2023-09-11" size-in-kilobytes="75.05859375">
  </log-entry>
</log-growth>
```

When I check in the system by left clicking on file then go to properties and it shows size on disk:  128 KB and size: 38 KB. So why am I not getting the result as system showing? Is there any specific function in MarkLogic so I could get the result as the system is showing? Any suggestions are much appreciated.

Comment: 38 * 2 is around 75, so maybe just remove the `* 2` in the `convertToKilobytes` function? Or use the size in characters directly, this may also be interesting depending on why you are measuring the size.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Marijn as per your comment "remove the * 2 in the convertToKilobytes" what should i use , "use the size in characters directly" , where should i use this , i am  measuring the size because i want to know how quickly increasing the size of logs

Comment: For the conversion: don't multiply with anything, so `declare function local:convertToKilobytes($sizeInCharacters as xs:integer) as xs:decimal 
{
 $sizeInCharacters div 1024
};`. I'm not sure if this calculation will actually be accurate when dealing with multi-byte characters etc, but at least in this example it will match the 38 KB that you got from your OS (I assume Windows?).

Comment: For using the size in characters or not: why do you want to know how quickly the size of the logs increase? Do you want to check if you have enough disk space? Or how fast you will be able to process the logs? Or which times in the day are the busiest? Something else? For some of these reasons an accurate size in kilobytes would be necessary (but you can estimate that more or less reliably by looking at the files in the file explorer I guess), for some other reasons the relative increase or related metrics like character count may be useful and easier/more reliable to compute.

Comment: @Marijn it is declare function local:convertToKilobytes($sizeInCharacters as xs:integer) as xs:decimal  {  $sizeInCharacters div 1024 }; it giving result nearly, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`xdmp:filesystem-file-length()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:filesystem-file-length) pointing to the ErrorLog.txt file:

```
xdmp:filesystem-file-length("C:\Program Files\MarkLogic\Data\Logs\ErrorLog.txt")
```

That will return the size in bytes, and then you can convert into the desired unit (i.e. `$bytes div 1024` for KB).

Comment: Thanks, it is so simple to get the result, and it is giving me the same result, but it is in only one line code, Thanks again.